# Using Regex to find Groups ( ) with Repeat { }

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to analyze the following block of text to collect the cultures + sub-cultures (ideally in groups 1 & 2 respectively):

> Home of the gods. Elysium, Avalon, earthly paradise.--Celtic (general): MacCulloch Celtic 14; Irish: ibid. 37f., 114ff., Cross; Welsh: ibid. 193; Icel.: MacCulloch Eddic 312ff.; Hindu: Penzer I 125 n. 1.; Jewish: Neuman.--Hawaii: Beckwith Myth 67; So. Am. Indian (Apapocuv\xe1-Guarani): M\xe9traux RMLP XXXIII 122; Africa (Fang): Trilles 130.

My best attempt so far is using the following Regex:

```
(\w+)\.?\:|(\w+\.?\s?){0,3}\((.*?)\)\:
```

Which results in the following:

```
[(u'', u'Celtic ', u'general'), (u'Irish', u'', u''), (u'Welsh', u'', u''), (u'Icel', u'', u''), (u'Hindu', u'', u''), (u'Jewish', u'', u''), (u'Hawaii', u'', u''), (u'', u'Indian ', u'Apapocuv\xe1-Guarani'), (u'', u'Africa ', u'Fang')]
```

The problem with it is that it is getting only 'Indian' before 'Apapocuv\xe1-Guarani' rather than So. Am. Indian.

Here is a breakdown on my logic / requirements for the whole system:

1. First Group `'(\w+)\.?\:'` is for Any Word ending in a : (Irish, Jewish, Hawaii, Hindu)
2. Second Group `'(\w+\.?\s?){0,3}'` is for specifically getting "So. Am. Indian" This is the section I'm having trouble on. I get Indian, but not So. Am. Indian. I will also need to get variations such as "So. Am. Indian, S. A. Indian, So. A. Indian, S. Am. Indian"
3. Third Group `'\((.*?)\)\'` (along with the second section) gets the additional sub-tribe so: Africa (Fang)

I'd love to have these work in two groups, but I can deal with three in the code later on. If anyone has any ideas, I'll be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Example (javascript)*

```
var s = "Home of the gods. Elysium, Avalon, earthly paradise.--Celtic (general): MacCulloch Celtic 14; Irish: ibid. 37f., 114ff., Cross; Welsh: ibid. 193; Icel.: MacCulloch Eddic 312ff.; Hindu: Penzer I 125 n. 1.; Jewish: Neuman.--Hawaii: Beckwith Myth 67; So. Am. Indian (Apapocuv\xe1-Guarani): M\xe9traux RMLP XXXIII 122; Africa (Fang): Trilles 130."
var rx = /(?:\-{2}|\;\s)((?:\w+\.\s)*\w+)(?:\s\(([^\)]+)\))?\:/g

while(m = rx.exec(s)){
    console.log(m[1] + ', ' + m[2]);
}
```

*Output*

```
Celtic, general
Irish, undefined
Welsh, undefined
Hindu, undefined
Jewish, undefined
Hawaii, undefined
So. Am. Indian, Apapocuvá-Guarani
Africa, Fang
```

Comment: Wow thank you! This worked really well and simplifies my two groups so thank you. My only question is (and perhaps I didn't specify clearly as I could have) it didn't allow for catching "So. Am. Indian" but rather just "Indian". I need to be able to catch if there are up to three abbreviated words prior, such as "So. Am. Indian, S. A. Indian, So. A. Indian, S. Am. Indian" Let me know if you know, and thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with adding a repeating operator like `{0,3}` onto a group is that the back-reference for that group will be overwritten every time it's matched.  If you want to capture the entire repeated match, you need to use nested groups:

```
(\w+).?\:|((\w+.?\s?){0,3})((.*?))\:
```

This will generate an extra back-reference (`\2` in this case) that you can simply ignore, but if that bothers you, many regex engines also have a `(?: )` syntax for non-referenced groups:

```
(\w+).?\:|((?:\w+.?\s?){0,3})((.*?))\:
```

Comment: Hrrmm... I tried both of these and they didn't give me good results. I'm using python and re.findall could you please tell me what you're using? thanks!